# IF Condition in Javascript - String is not recognize

Tags: javascript

I have this code on JS and value of searchFilter is "Filter by Code and Name" but it didn't pass on the IF Statement. Please help on the better If condition statement.

```
    var searchFilter = $("#SearchString").val();
if (searchFilter.toString == "Filter by Code or Name.")
```

Comment: `toString()`???

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually invoke the function:

```
if (searchFilter.toString() == "Filter by Code or Name.")
```